# Solving $ \{ \varnothing, \{ x\} \} = \{ y, \{ \varnothing \} \}$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The equation is:

$$ \{ \varnothing, \{ x\} \} = \{ y, \{ \varnothing \} \}$$

where $ \varnothing $ denotes empty set.

I guess I need to break this into cases for each side. Help me get started.

Comment: Isn't it just $x=y=\emptyset$?

Comment: @DietrichBurde That would be my conclusion too.

Comment: Note {$\emptyset$}$\ne\emptyset$ because {$\emptyset$} isn’t empty, so @DietrichBurde’s conclusion follows

Comment: You're being asked to prove that with at least a little detail.  Hint: How many members does $\emptyset$ have?  How many elements does $\{\emptyset\}$ have?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, you have to look at several cases:

1. Since $\varnothing$ is a member of the left-hand side, then it is also a member of the right-hand side.
2. Since the members of the right-hand side are $y$ and $\left\{\varnothing\right\}$, then $\varnothing=\left\{\varnothing\right\}$ or $\varnothing=y$.
3. However, $\varnothing\in\left\{\varnothing\right\}$, whereas $\varnothing\not\in\varnothing$. Therefore $\varnothing\neq\left\{\varnothing\right\}$.
4. By 2. and 3., the only possibility is $\varnothing=y$.

Now do a similar analysis for $\left\{x\right\}$, knowing that $y=\varnothing$, and conclude that $x=\varnothing$.

Answer (score 2):

Two sets are equal if they have exactly the same elements.

so, $\emptyset$ must be in $\{y,\{\emptyset\}\}$

but, it is known that
$\emptyset \ne \{\emptyset\}$

thus

$$\emptyset=y$$

and
$$\{x\}=\{\emptyset\}$$
which means that
$$x=\emptyset=y$$

Comment: The conclusion "and $\left\{x\right\}=\left\{\varnothing\right\}$" needs to be justified because "$\left\{x\right\}\neq\varnothing$", for completeness

Comment: @LuizCordeiro I said they have Exactly the same elements.

Answer (score 1):

Break things into cases!

Two sets are equal iff they have the same elements. In particular, we have $$\{a,b\}=\{u,v\}\quad\iff\quad \mbox{EITHER ($a=u$ and $b=v$) OR ($a=v$ and $b=u$).}$$

*(NOTE: this isn't an exclusive "or," since we could have $a=b=u=v$.)*

In this case, this tells us that in order to have the desired equality we must have one of the following:

- $\emptyset=y$, $\{x\}=\{\emptyset\}$.
- $\color{red}{\emptyset=\{\emptyset\}}$, $y=\{x\}$.

Note the red clause: $\emptyset=\{\emptyset\}$ **is not true** (this is important to understand), so that second bulletpoint can't hold.

So our only option is the first bulletpoint. That is, $$x=y=\emptyset.$$

Comment: The "either" part of your equivalence only holds if we assume "$a\neq b$" or "$u\neq v$"

Comment: @LuizCordeiro I didn't say **exclusive** or! (And I've edited to make that explicit.)

Comment: From my understanding, "either $A$ or $B$" means **exclusive** or (https://english.stackexchange.com/a/13892/330736), but I guess this could vary... Anyway, thanks

Comment: @LuizCordeiro From that very answer: " If they say "if either A or B is true", though, they probably mean a non-exclusive OR, and the condition is still true if both A and B are true."

Answer (score 0):

If two sets are equal, then they have exactly the same elements in each. Since $\emptyset$ is an element of the LHS, it is an element of the RHS. It cannot be $\{\emptyset\}$, since that is not empty, so $y=\emptyset$. It follows that $\{x\}=\{\emptyset\}$, which implies that $x=\emptyset$ also.